# Disable "group becomes tuple" behavior of Python's re.findall()

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

When I use a regex in **Python 2.x** containing two or more groups, `re.findall()` returns a list of n-tuples for the n groups contained by the regex. I know it's supposed to work like this but is there any way to circumvent this behavior?

For instance, when I run

```
import re
sentence = 'We also learned that the !!probability of an outcome is its relative frequency over endless repetitions of the experiment. '
print re.findall(r'[Pp]robabilit(y|ies)',sentence)
```

it returns just `['y']`. However, I would like to have `probability` returned instead. For a different sentence, containing "probabilities", I'd like to have `probabilities` returned, and so on.

Answer (score 6):

The behavior of the [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) change when there are one or more groups exist. It returns a list of groups; a list of tuples if there are more than one group.

You can get what you want by make the group as non-capturing group:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[Pp]robabilit(?:y|ies)',sentence)
['probability']
```

Alternatively using [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) and list comprehension:

```
>>> [m.group() for m in re.finditer(r'[Pp]robabilit(y|ies)',sentence)]
['probability']
```